# Virgin Money Travel Insurance

Tags: travel-insurance-claim

While making a claim for a cancelled holiday I received a claim form from Virgin and also claim forms from Insure and Go,their underwriters,who want all my bank details and statements.Is this normal practice?If I send the details to Virgin Money can`t they inform Insure and Go?

Comment: Have you checked your travel policy T&C / information about making a claim? They may just be looking for proof of your booking; your bank details will be necessary if they are going to reimburse your account direct.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It sounds like you would be happy for Virgin Money to send your details to Insure and Go, so what's the problem with sending your details yourself? The time you've taken to write this question and wait for answers is surely greater than the time it would take to just fill in the form as you've been asked to.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is for the legal reasons, at least in US (and I am speculating that UK is similar on that matter).

The insurer typically requires the claim form to be signed by the insured (or beneficiary) to start the claim process. This signature has important legal consequences - for example the claim has to be processed under certain period. And you are legally responsible to provide truthful information - this includes other documents, such as bank statements, which support the claim amount. So someone who just sold you the policy cannot do this for you, even if they got the copies.

It is also in your best interest to work directly with the insurer (which I assume is InsureAndGo). Adding someone into the intermediate loop increases the chance some paperwork would get lost in mail, and this would make it much more difficult to track it. And handling insurance is annoying enough even without this.